# how will i make sure the email address actually exist or not?

Tags: php, smtp

Email Address validation: How to make sure that the email address actually exist. I am having problem because the users are signing up with anyone email address.

Comment: A lot of websites skirt around this issue by requiring email validation. i.e. send the email address a link that has url parameters in it that you can use to verify the email address when it is visited.

Answer (score 7):

you can send a verification link to given email address.
user will click the verification link and email address will be verified.

Comment: The link should point to a page with `Confirm` button/form.  Otherwise some "aggressive" spam protection tools may trigger unintentional "confirmation".